# How do I filter and sum only negative or positive numbers in a field using an expression in SQL Reporting Services 2014

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

How do I filter and sum only negative numbers in a field using an expression in SQL Reporting Services 2014?  The field Amt has both negatives (revenue) and positives (expenses) that I want to total in two different columns.

```
IIf(Fields!Amt.Value<0,SUM(Fields!Amt.Value<0),0) - Revenue


IIf(Fields!Amt.Value>0,(Fields!Amt.Value>0),0) - Expenses
```

This does not work, but you get the idea of what I'm trying to do.  Sorry, I'm new at report writing.  This is likely pretty simple for most of you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need something like this (and reversed for the other column)

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!Amt.Value<0, Fields!Amt.Value, 0))
```

You should think of it as...

> For each row, evaluate if it's < 0, if it is then return the value,
>   else return 0. THEN we sum the results of all these returned values.

Often people think about it the wrong way round. You'll soon do it instinctively with a little practice.

**Here's a complete example**

I created a new report then..
I created a sample dataset as follows.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (SomeText varchar(10), Amt float)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('A', -2.5),
('A', 2.5),
('A', 1),
('A', 0.5),
('B', -2.5),
('B', -0.5),
('B', 0.5),
('B', -0.1),
('C', -1),
('C', -2),
('C', 3),
('C', 4),
('C', -5)

SELECT * FROM @t
```

I then added a table to the report and added a row group, grouped by the `SomeText` field

The report design looks like this..

[image]
The expressions in the Rev and Exp columns are as follows.

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!Amt.Value<0, Fields!Amt.Value, 0))
```

and

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!Amt.Value>0, Fields!Amt.Value, 0))
```

respectively.

The final output looks like this.

[image]

If you still get errors then check the datatypes  in your recordset and post the output from it.

Comment: I'm getting #Error when I use the above syntax

Comment: I'll post a full example but the code should work. Give me 10 mins

Comment: The answer just needs a little tweek on it as below;
``` =SUM(CDec(IIF(Fields!Amt.Value>0, Fields!Amt.Value, 0)))
``` Works as magic